# How to use calendar to create date

Tags: java, calendar

i need to use Calendar to create date at which i specify the month , the week number and the day of week.
i am creating new instance of calendar:
**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,7);
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,1);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH,10);
```

**
when calling c.getTime();
instead of getting the first Saturday of November  i am getting the last Saturday of october?

Comment: Please fix your variable names, unless this isn't `java.util.Calendar`. Also what do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Now you change all your values...

Comment: do i have to specify the first day of the week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DAY_OF_WEEK` is Sunday through Saturday. The value 7, indicates `SATURDAY`. The `WEEK_OF_MONTH` is

> Field number for get and set indicating the week number within the
>   current month. The first week of the month, as defined by
>   getFirstDayOfWeek() and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(), has value 1.
>   Subclasses define the value of WEEK_OF_MONTH for days before the first
>   week of the month.

The `MONTH` numbers start at 0, so `10` is November. You haven't specified a year, so it uses the current year.

November's first week Saturday falls on

```
Sat Nov 02 11:19:24 EDT 2013
```

What else are you expecting? October? Change your `MONTH` value to `9`.

Comment: NO, I NEED TO GET THE FIRST SATURDAY OF NOVEMBER , BUT I AM GETTING THE LAST SATURDAY OF OCTOBER.

Comment: @primeFaceUser Stop screaming. The code you currently have gives the first Saturday of November.

Comment: but it is returning 26 October and that's my problem i need to solve this unusual problem.

Comment: @primeFaceUser My answer explains exactly what `WEEK_OF_MONTH` is. You can also read the javadoc. The code you currently have in your question is for `Sat Nov 02 11:19:24 EDT 2013`.

Comment: It was returning 26 October because the first day of week is 7(Saturday) so in order to solve this i have set the first day of week to be the first day of month.

Comment: @primeFaceUser I don't know what to tell you, you were running some other code, not the one in your question.

Comment: nope, it is same try put the first day of week to be 7 then run this code you will get 26 October instead of 2 nov. it is a matter of locale, moreover you helped me solving this @sotirios.

Comment: @primeFaceUser Surprising that it's a Locale problem. Some fields must have priority over others. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct Calendar constants values. Please refer to below code it works fine. **Please remember Month value in calendar starts with 0 and 1 ie, month as 0 means month as Jan**.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,4);
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,4);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  c.set(2000, 7, 4);  // YYYY M D

  // print the result
  System.out.println("Altered date is :" + cal.getTime());
```